# How can i see all parameters of a function in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, function, parameters, data-science

dir(pd) shows only some of pandas functions not all, but in documentation there are a lot of them that are quite handy. Is there any way to see list of all functions and particularly their parameters with some code? Thanks

Comment: You can look at `dir(pd.DataFrame)` and `dir(pd.Series)` but fundamentally you need to read the documentation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Nick thanks it solves half my problem. Is there any way to see arguments of each function of DataFrame without having to look into documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the help() method to get the signature and details of any function. e.g. help(pd.DataFrame.apply)